# What is the difference between XML and RDF

Tags: ontology

Since XML already has namespaces and schema.
What is the difference between RDF and XML and where is RDF used?

Comment: This is not a programming question. Probably all you need is to [read the article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Description_Framework).